# Add namespaces and prefixes to soap message header during serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, soap

I am trying to generate an xml file with the following structure :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header>
     <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wsse curity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" soap:mustunderstand="1">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-t oken-profile-1.0#passwordtext">secret</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
   </wsse:Security>
 </soap-env:Header>
```

The xml i get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap-env:Header>
   <wsse:Security>
     <wsse:UsernameToken>
       <wsse:Username>someuser</wsse:Username>
       <wsse:Password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#passwordtext">somepass</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
   </wsse:Security>
 </soap-env:Header>
```

The classes i have are :

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")] //
public class SoapEnvelope<T>
{
    public Header Header { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Body")]
    public GenericBody<T> GenericBody { get; set; }
}


[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Security", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
public class Header
{
    public Security Security { get; set; }
}


 public class Security
{
    public UsernameToken UsernameToken { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
 public class UsernameToken
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public Passwords Password { get; set; }
}

public class Passwords
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; } 
    [XmlText]
    public string Passowrd { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that when i declare the namespaces with the class `XmlSerializerNamespaces` like this :

```
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SoapEnvelope<T>));

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = false, Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
        var soapwriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlSettings);

        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("soap-env", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        ns.Add("wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
        //ns.Add("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        serializer.Serialize(soapwriter, soapEnveloped, ns);
        soapwriter.Close();
```

I get both of the namespaces in the root element, and no namespace in the element `Security`. And also how do i manage to add also the two other namespaces  at `Security` element : `xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" soap:mustunderstand="1"`
Have tried different ways i found while searching these days but none of them seems to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get both of the namespaces in the root element

This is semantically equivalent to the XML you're trying to generate. You can't control this with `XmlSerializer` - the first thing it will do is write all the namespace bindings in the root element. You shouldn't have any reason to be concerened about this, however.

> And also how do i manage to add also the two other namespaces at Security element : xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" soap:mustunderstand="1"

There are two things here: one is a namespace binding, and one is an attribute. If you add the attribute correctly, the namespace binding will be added in the root along with the others:

```
public class Security
{
    [XmlAttribute("mustunderstand", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public int MustUnderstand { get; set; }

    public UsernameToken UsernameToken { get; set; }
}
```

This gives the output below, which is equivalent to your expected output:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-2004
01-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soa
p/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Header>
    <wsse:Security soap-env:mustunderstand="1">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>someuser</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401
-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#passwordtext">somepass</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap-env:Header>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JEC4H3) for a working demo.